# Document management for Drupal 6?

Tags: drupal, document

Can anyone tell me if there is a similar module for document management for Drupal 6 like docMan for Joomla? I want to be able to manage documents from one place (upload etc) and then be able to link to those documents from within a page.

Thanks in advance,

Ben

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a module, you can do this simply by creating a node type for documents, then attaching a filefield to upload upload a document per node, and then using a module like [Insert](http://drupal.org/project/insert) to link to the file from other nodes.

For listings of documents, use the [views](http://drupal.org/project/views) module.

Comment: Many thanks Mark. That's helpful, I will have a look at this solution.

Answer (score 0):

There is also the webfilemanager module.  http://drupal.org/project/webfm
I've found this module to be quite handy for managing any kind of file.  I allows for tree-like folder structures and is quite versatile.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it sounds good. I will have a look.

Answer (score 0):

A colleague of mine recently had nice things to say about [fieldepot](http://drupal.org/project/filedepot).  He attended the recent [Waterloo Region Drupal Users Group meeting](http://groups.drupal.org/node/71553) and heard Blaine from [Nextide](http://www.nextide.ca/) speak to it.

Comment: Many thanks Craig. I'll check it out. I'll be going to a Drupal meet up in London this Monday and will probably get more answers I'm sure.